# how to get getActionBar object in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

[image]
I am trying to get getActionBar object in android .I am getting **null** value why ?
Here is my main java file

```
package com.example.naveen.tabfragment;


import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Tab Variable


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar =getActionBar();


    }
}
```

**App gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.naveen.tabfragment"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

**manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.naveen.tabfragment" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
     />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**style.xml** file

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

I am getting null value on this line

**ActionBar actionBar =getActionBar();**

I am using android studio .and testing on MOTOE 4.4.2

Comment: Since you're using `AppCompat` as your theme, you should be using `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`, and `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Comment: I tried it and getting  above error please check above..please check my updated one

Answer (score 2):

If your are using support library you should use 
getSupportedActionBar() method. 
You should also import proper class from supported library not from normal one.

Comment: which class  i need to import

Comment: you can import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`

Comment: If you don't exactly know which class should be imported, simple method is to remove imports ex. with word ActonBar and allow Android Studio to prompt you with new imports. Remember to choose one with "support" word in it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29

read reference on google. At the top of the page you should find class name which should be imported. In that case, as Selim mentioned it should be:[android.support.v7.app.ActionBar]

Answer (score 1):

Your Theme is *AppCompat* ,so your extends class must be `AppCompatActivity` instead of Activity.

If you extends AppcompatActivity class then use `getSupportActionBar()` instead `getActionBar().`

So,Finally

**`ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar ();`**

I hope it helps you.